# What is the fastest way to redirect a user using php?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a site that runs on php and I have to redirect the user when the user logs in, comments, or posts. I am trying to cut down on time with redirects as much as possible, and to redirect a user to another page, I currently use:

```
 echo "<script>location.href='www.redirect.url'</script>";
```

I am new to using PHP to redirect users and this is the fastest way that I know, is there a faster way? And if so, what is it?

Comment: Take a look at php `header()` function

Comment: `header("Location: http://www.redirect.url");exit;`

Comment: what is the use of the `exit;` command at the end?

Comment: makes sure noting below gets executed when we redirect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, my site seems to be running slightly more smooth. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest option is issuing a raw HTTP header:

```
header("Location: http://www.redirect.url");
exit;
```

The exit is to make sure nothing below gets executed when we redirect.

important note: there can be no output sent before the call.

less important, you should if you can use the full URI

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php